# Android Alert Dialog text color

Tags: android, text, android-alertdialog

In my application I am trying to switch the themes between light and dark. But the Alert Dialog text color is not changed with the theme. I have created a theme for the Alert Dialog but does not seem to be working. Here is my code :

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.DialogWhite));

    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
            final ActionBarItemResource eab = aList.get(which);
            eab.getAction().run();

        }
    });
    // builder.setTitle(tEntityNew.getName());
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

my styles.xml

```
   <style name="DialogWhite" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly</item>
    </style>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Making custom dialog is much simpler to produce most fit UIs in this case. Since only limited themes are provided in AlertDialog